# ajax get multiple arrays from ajax.request.responseText

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new in AJAX. My php code pass two multidimensional arrays to javascript code. How I can get multiple arrays from `ajax.request.responseText` ?.

My scriptPHP code is:
..
.
    echo json_encode($datachart,$datachart1);  // both are multidimensional arrays

My JavaScript is:

```
function SomeFunction(scriptPHP) {
  var ajax = new ajaxRequest(scriptPHP, function () {
    var responseData = JSON.parse(ajax.request.responseText);
    alert(responseData["0"]);
  });
};
```

But Alert() not show on the screen, not appear; I think `JSON.parse` is not working. When pass one single array this work fine.

Please, someone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the console

Comment: try without JSON.parse.

Comment: It is not important for json , that is just data please check network tab

Comment: Fast Snail, how check the console?. Thank u.

Comment: Pass argument to function and check that argument in alert using stringify method.

Answer (score 0):

WIll Work 100%

```
  function SomeFunction(url) {
                new Ajax.Request(url, {
                   method: 'get',
                   onSuccess: successFunc,
                   onFailure:  failureFunc
                });
             }
             function successFunc(response) {
                if (200 == response.status) {
                   var responseData = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                   alert(responseData["0"]);
                } 
             }
```